# Bluetooth connectivity for android devices in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-bluetooth

I want to build a simple Bluetooth API to be integrated in unity app so that users can connect to other users  within the app and then send and receive data via bluetooth.
I did some searching and some of the solutions said to first build a .jar file addressing the bluetooth properties and run the same file in unity using some method in C#. But I was thinking of the Networking library in the unityengine to achieve the same thing.
Could someone provide me further references to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the operating systems bluetooth libraries. It is not possible to access Androids bluetooth-stack from within Mono.

But, as you suggested yourself, you can create an [Android-Plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) which handles the bluetooth part.